# add icons to viewBox

Tags: c#, wpf, chess

I have a Viewbox as ChessBoard

```
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" Background="{StaticResource Checkerboard}" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

How i can add icon to the rectangles?

Comment: Also... Have you actually tried something for the icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... Your chess board is the `ItemsControl`, not the `Viewbox`. The `Viewbox` is simply containing the board for some special visualization woe we don't know (Maybe so you can use a `Height` of 8 without it appearing extremely tiny?).

Since you're using an `ItemsControl`, the correct way would be adding items to it and setting several DataTemplates, one for each type of piece. The "icon" would go inside each `DataTemplate`.

For instance, if your chess pieces are defined like this:

```cs
public class ChessPiece
{
    public ColorEnum Color { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsAValidMovement(int x, int y)
    {
        // base common logic
    }
}

public class QueenPiece : ChessPiece
{
    public override bool IsAValidMovement(int x, int y)
    {
        if (base.IsAValidMovement(x, y))
        {
            // specific logic
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you should do something like this:

```xml
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" Background="{StaticResource Checkerboard}" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <!-- You could also bind ItemsSource to a collection of chess pieces -->
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <local:QueenPiece Color="Black" X="3" Y="0" />
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

And in your `Resources` include a `DataTemplate` of the correct `TargetType`:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:QueenPiece}">
        <Grid Height="1" Width="1" />
            <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="queen-white.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="Black">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Source" Value="queen-black.png" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'll leave positioning the pieces to you :P

Answer (score 0):

A ItemControl is normally used to contain a collection of items.The ItemsPanelTemplate in the ItemControl usually describes how you want that collection of items to be displayed. These are normally generic types provided for by Microsoft. These include the WrapPanel and StackPanel. The item itself would be underneath the ItemTemplate. There you have the item template be customized to the viewmodel that is in the itemsource.

This should be how you look at it to start out.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard" Width="50">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Canvas Height="10"
                                Width="10"
                                Background="{Binding Color}">

                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The setting of the items control is done in the code behind.

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<stage> l = new List<stage>();
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "White" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "Black" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "White" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "Black" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "White" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "Black" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "White" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "Black" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "White" });
        l.Add(new stage() { Color = "Black" });
        ChessBoard.ItemsSource = l;
    }
```

I need to let you know, this is not really a robust way of doing these thing. But this is the right direction you want to head in. But to just get an image in the canvas you will just need to add in an imagecontrol and bind to source.

```
<Canvas Height="10"
        Width="10"
        Background="{Binding Color}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
</Canvas>
```